# Scheduled Thread Pool with timeout - possible approaches

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

I know `@Synchronized` in `spring-boot` (`spring boot` is my base technology). However, it can't allow me to set timeout for scheduled funtion.

I heard about java 8 concurrent features, but I am not sure if it can help me.

To sum up:
Periodical (at each `0.5s`)  execution thread from some limited thread pool and possibility of timeout this scheduled tread.

Any ideas ?

Comment: "However, it can't allow me to set timeout for scheduled function." Is this a requirement?

Comment: @efekctive, yes timeout is crucial requirment

Comment: I read it as the value of the timeout can not be changed. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be fixed\

Answer (score 0):

Consider [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

`scheduleAtFixedRate()` lets you schedule tasks to be  executed after a specified delay and executed again based on the period you specified.

`scheduleWithFixedDelay()` lets you create tasks that will be executed after the initial delay and then subsequently with provided delay between the termination of last execution and start of another execution.